# Spring Boot with Vaadin | Always lands on "You're offline" page , is there any configuration which alters such behaviour?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I've been stuck here since a while now

My Vaadin with Spring boot app just lands me to the "You're Offline" page everytime, Tried changing configurations but wasn't sure ablout which specific config i needed to change.

```
package com.example.demofinal;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.BodySize;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Viewport;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableWebSecurity
@ImportResource("classpath:http-beans.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, viewport-fit=cover")
@Push()
@PWA(name = "File Upload App", shortName = "Upload App")
@BodySize(height = "100vh", width = "100vw")
@PageTitle("File Upload App")
public class DemofinalApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemofinalApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.demofinal.views;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.receivers.MultiFileMemoryBuffer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Route("upload")
public class UploadView extends VerticalLayout {


    public UploadView() {
        add(new H1("File Upload Form"));
        MultiFileMemoryBuffer buffer = new MultiFileMemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
        Button uploadButton = new Button("Upload");
        TextField appVersionField = new TextField("App Version");
        TextField userIdField = new TextField("UserId");
        add(userIdField, appVersionField, upload, uploadButton);

        upload.setUploadButton(uploadButton);
        upload.setAcceptedFileTypes("application/pdf", "image/jpeg", "image/png");

        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
            String userId = userIdField.getValue();
            String appVersion = appVersionField.getValue();

            try (InputStream inputStream = buffer.getInputStream(event.getFileName());
                 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                // Create a MultiValueMap to hold the file and other form data
                MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                body.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(outputStream.toByteArray()) {
                    @Override
                    public String getFilename() {
                        return event.getFileName();
                    }
                });
                body.add("userId", userId);
                body.add("appVersion", appVersion);

                // Create a HttpHeaders object with Content-Type as multipart/form-data
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

                // Create a HttpEntity with body and headers
                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

                // Make a POST request to your Spring Boot API endpoint
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                        "http://localhost:9099/debug", // Replace with your API endpoint URL
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        requestEntity,
                        String.class
                );

                // Handle the API response if needed
                String apiResponse = response.getBody();
                Notification.show("API Response: " + apiResponse, 5000, Notification.Position.BOTTOM_START);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle exceptions, for example, show an error message to the user
                Notification.show("Error uploading file: " + e.getMessage(), 5000, Notification.Position.BOTTOM_START);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

vaadin.whitelisted-packages=com.example.demofinal.*,com.vaadin
vaadin.load-on-startup=true

I tried changing configurations which might be related to this issue but wasn't able to find the Root Cause for this issue. Help!!

Comment: Use the spring security configuration provided by Vaadin in their docs.